# I want to find and replace content on sheets with google apps script to have history of changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have an active webhook, every time someone sends a form on my web page I register the entry data on my Google Sheets and saves it on a new folder or an already created folder with the user email as Title of the folder.

But when the user sends form again, it creates another file with the same name, instead of replacing the older one, I would like to replace the content of the older one instead of creating a new file.

Because like this, I can see all the changes that the user made.

This is my code:

```
function copyFile(mappedEntry) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXXXXXXXX");
    var source_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXX")
    var parent_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXX");

    // Make a backup copy.
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var nameOfChildFolder = activeSheet.getRange("B1").getValue() + ' ' + activeSheet.getRange("A4").getValue();

    var file2 = file.makeCopy('xxx-  ' + activeSheet.getRange("C7").getValue() + ' ' + activeSheet.getRange("A4").getValue() + ' ' + formattedDate + ' ' + activeSheet.getRange("B1").getValue());

    var finalFolder = getFolder(parent_folder, nameOfChildFolder);

    if (finalFolder) {
        finalFolder.addFile(file2);
    } 
    else {
        finalFolder = parent_folder.createFolder(nameOfChildFolder);
        finalFolder.addFile(file2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you are looking to do. Does every user get a folder with their username that contains a spreadsheet with just their answers in it?

Comment: Daniel, I'm the third person who is telling you that we don't fully understand your scenario. As Cooper says, read up on how to create a Minimal and Complete example. Then edit your question to describe, in detail, what happens when a user sends an email from your website, which procedures are automated, which are manual... what happens now, but what changes do you want to make, etc, etc. You are sure to get assistance, but only once we understand your scenario.